# Условие для индекса

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с индексом который необходимо модифицировать так, чтобы оно ограничивало еще и поле `type` таким образом чтобы `type` мог принимать только три значения `LONG`, `SHORT`, `UNIVERSAL`.

По правилу: либо строка должна быть `UNIVERSAL` тогда никаких дубликатов по комбинации `symbol_id, account_id, enabled`. Либо допускать один `LONG`, и один `SHORT` для комбинации `symbol_id, account_id, enabled`.

Или другими словами c уникальной комбинацией `symbol_id, account_id, enabled` где `enabled == TRUE` может быть либо:

1. Один универсальный инстанс (`UNIVERSAL` это означает что он работает и как `LONG`, и как `SHORT`).
2. Два инстанса, один `LONG`, и один `SHORT`.
3. У любого инстанса хотя бы один `LONG`, или `SHORT` должен быть `true`

`LONG`, и `SHORT` могут существовать и по отдельности то есть на пример `LONG` есть, а `SHORT` отсутствует и не планируется. Либо наоборот.

```
-- Instances
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instances
(
    id            BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    enabled       BOOLEAN      NOT NULL,
    title         VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    type          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    status        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    updated_at    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    last_callback TIMESTAMP,
    settings      VARCHAR(255),
    user_id       BIGINT REFERENCES users (id),
    symbol_id     BIGINT REFERENCES symbols (id),
    account_id    BIGINT REFERENCES accounts (id),
    strategy_id   BIGINT REFERENCES strategies (id)
);
```

И индекс:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_symbol_account_enabled
    ON instances (symbol_id, account_id, enabled)
    WHERE (enabled IS TRUE);
```

Вероятно это должно быть что-то вроде:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_symbol_account_enabled_type
    ON instances (symbol_id, account_id, enabled, type)
    WHERE (enabled IS TRUE
        AND (type = 'UNIVERSAL' OR type = 'SHORT' OR type = 'LONG')
        );
```

Только не одно из 3х значений а по описанному выше правилу.
Как это правильно написать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если изменения схемы допустимы, то предлагаю вот такой (упрощённый)
вариант:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t_1 (
  symbol_id  BIGINT  NOT NULL
, account_id BIGINT  NOT NULL
, enabled    BOOLEAN NOT NULL
, long       BOOLEAN NOT NULL
, short      BOOLEAN NOT NULL
, CHECK (long OR short)
)
;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
    ON t_1(symbol_id, account_id)
 WHERE (enabled AND short)
;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
    ON t_1(symbol_id, account_id)
 WHERE (enabled AND long)
;
```

Соответственно ваш тип `'UNIVERSAL'` превращается в запись,
где выполяется условие `long AND short`.

---

Если схему менять нельзя, то:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
    ON t_1(symbol_id, account_id)
 WHERE (enabled AND type IN ('UNIVERSAL', 'LONG'))
;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
    ON t_1(symbol_id, account_id)
 WHERE (enabled AND type IN ('UNIVERSAL', 'SHORT'))
;
```

Comment: забыл про условие что у любого инстанса должен быть или `long` или `short` в `true`. Не поможете это тоже добавить?

Comment: @Pavel  Эм…  Вы случаем `CHECK` в определении таблицы не пропустили?